# Enable "performance mode" for existing aws amplify env

Tags: aws-amplify

I was looking for ways to improve performance of my aws amplify application and got some hits to enable for my existing application [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ttl.html#Performance-mode). But when I follow the given steps, I don't see the option **"Enable performance mode.**" in step 5, given the screenshot below.

[image]

In the action dropdown I only see "Disconnect branch". I am not sure what's wrong with my amplify app settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its not obvious if its possible to enable performance mode from aws console. What worked for me was from `aws cli`. I updated my `aws cli` to latest version (2.2.3) from (2.0.3) which does not had option `--enable-performance-mode`, and ran update command e.g

`aws amplify update-branch --app-id xxxxx --branch-name prod --enable-performance-mode`

Now I can see performance mode is enabled in aws console.
[image]